# Get List of objects from database

Tags: php, list, object, mysqli

I have a class called Person, with its getters and setters, and I want to know how I can return a List from Data Layer. In C# I use List and I can return the list, but in PHP I don't know how.

```
function AllPersons()
{
    try 
    {
        $objConn = new Connection();
        $conn = $objConn ->Connect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
        $answer= mysqli_query($cn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($answer) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($answer)) 
            {
                /*here i want to do something like in C#
                  List<Person>listPerson;
                  listPerson.add(objPerson);*/
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;

        }
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        //FB::log("nada");
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to return an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array and fill it.

```
$listPerson = [];   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($answer)) {
    $listPerson[] = new Person($row);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In PHP arrays replace the use of Lists/Arrays you'd use in .NET.
They're really flexible when it comes down to mutations.

In this case you'd probably approach it like:

```
...

$persons = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($answer)) 
{
    // Using [] appends the content of $row to the $persons array.
    $persons[] = $row;
}

...
```

Read more [about the flexibility of PHPs arrays here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

**List** is a dimensionless array in C# (Can also be used in dimensional). The arrays in PHP also dimensionless. So you can use arrays.

```
...
$listPerson = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($answer)) 
{
   $listPerson[] = new objPerson($row);
}
...
```